# Converted .net framework 3.5 to 4.0 now i get a scripting error whenever i try to do a postback

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, .net-4.0, postback

The action is being fired from a button inside an update panel.  I have triggers on the button as well.

This is the Error:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

When i view the trace this is the function it is failing on:

```
function Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_endPostBack
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code being executed

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace?

Comment: I believe the problem to be that im using telerik controls on the forms.  There is a couple forms that don't use any telerik controls and they work fine.  I think i need to update my telerik framework contols to 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

A general idea:

Where do you call it from ? Local IIS or VS Devserver ?

If iss, check if the AppPool of the Site points already to 4.0.

Cheers Sascha